# Test if contents of string array are in String

Tags: javascript

I'm currently hardcoding testing if a file extension is in a string.

My hardcode way with one extension is

```
var extension = /(\.txt)$/i;

var testFile = "myTest.txt";

alert(extension.test(testFile));
```

I plan to make this database driven and sent the file extensions in a comma separated list.

How can I parse a comma separated list and test if my String extension is in that list?

```
var testFile = "mytest.txt"
var validExtensions = "xlsx,txt,csv";
```

Comment: Split and compare each?

Comment: Somebody actually down-voted this.  I swear some of the people on this site are on a serious high-horse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the OR operator, pipeline.

```
var extension = /(\.txt|\.xls|\.csv)$/i;
```

Using input string:

```
var extensionsString = 'csv|txt|xlsx';
var pattern = new RegExp('(\.)(' + extensionsString + ')$', 'ig');
console.log('somepath/somefile.txt'.match(pattern));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions to assert the position of the match at the end of the string.

Instead, you can use ECMAScript6 [`String.prototype.endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith), which can be [polyfilled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith#Polyfill).

```js
validExtensions.split(',').some(ext => testFile.endsWith('.' + ext));
```

Answer (score 0):

Split an array and use each item in your regular expression:

```
validExtensions.split(',').some(function(ext) {
  return new RegExp('(\.' + ext + ')$').test(fileName);
});
```